# Return one row for each ID based on date column (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

The DDL creates the schema and data. I am looking for a **where** statement where it returns only one row for each ID and that row would be the last inserted row based on the inserteddate column.

So the result would be John, 5 and Debbie, 5

```
select Table1.Name, Table2.Rating
From table1 join table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
where inserteddate = max(insertedate)
```

.. for each ID? It seems simple but I am having a brain block.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Table1ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2](
    [Table2ID] [int] NULL,
    [InsertedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Rating] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]([Table1ID], [Name])
SELECT 1, N'John' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'Debbie'
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]([Table2ID], [InsertedDate], [Rating])
SELECT 1, '20090101 00:00:00.000', N'6' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20090401 00:00:00.000', N'5' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20090202 00:00:00.000', N'3' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20090303 00:00:00.000', N'5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.Name, Table2.Rating
FROM
  table1 
INNER JOIN 
  table2 ON table1.Table1ID = table2.Table2ID
WHERE
  inserteddate = (SELECT MAX(InsertedDate) 
                    FROM Table2 t2 
                   WHERE t2.Table2ID = Table2.Table2ID)
```

In this case, an index on the `InsertedDate` column would be very helpful!

Or if you're on SQL Server 2005 and up, you could also use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a ROW_NUMBER() and a PARTITION OVER statement like this:

```
WITH HelperCTE AS
(
  SELECT
    Table1.Name, Table2.Rating,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Table1.Table1ID 
                      ORDER BY Table2.InsertedDate DESC) AS 'RowNum'
  FROM
    table1 
  INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.Table1ID = table2.Table2ID
)
SELECT Name, Rating FROM HelperCTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This creates like a "temporary" view (the CTE) and numbers the entries partitioned by Table1ID (individual numbering for each separate Table1ID) and orders them descending by `InsertedDate` - so for each unique Table1ID, the most recent entry will have RowNum = 1.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this will do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1(
    [Table1ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #Table2(
    [Table2ID] [int] NULL,
    [InsertedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Rating] [varchar](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Table1([Table1ID], [Name])
SELECT 1, N'John' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, N'Debbie'
INSERT INTO #Table2([Table2ID], [InsertedDate], [Rating])
SELECT 1, '20090101 00:00:00.000', N'6' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20090401 00:00:00.000', N'5' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20090202 00:00:00.000', N'3' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20090303 00:00:00.000', N'5'


select x.name, t2.rating
from 
(
select t1.table1id, t1.name, max(t2.inserteddate) as inserteddate
from #table1 t1
join
#table2 t2
on
t1.table1id = t2.table2id
group by t1.table1id, t1.name
) x
join
#table2 t2
on
x.table1id = t2.table2id
and 
x.inserteddate = t2.inserteddate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    table1.name,
    table2.rating
from
    table1
    inner join table2 on 
        table2.id = (select top 1 t2.id from table2 t2 where table1.id = t2.id order by t2.inserteddate desc)
```

oh wait, table2 doesn't have a primary key? then...

```
select
    table1.name,
    (select top 1 t2.rating 
    from table2 t2 
    where table1.id = t2.id order by t2.inserteddate desc) as last_rating
from
    table1
```